# How to include Websphere plugin jars in WAS classpath

Tags: java, jdbc, websphere, websphere-8

I am facing classpath issue related to jars in WAS plugins folder. My application had IBM specific code to get compiled using the com.ibm.ws.runtime jar as mentioned below.

Location : C:\Program Files\IBM\Websphere\AppServer\Plugins

Source code:

Object obj = ((**com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcUtil.getNativeConnection**((**com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection**)connect)));

Both classes are available in com.ibm.ws.runtime

Compiled successfully by including IBM runtime.jar in classpath of build process but after the deployment in WAS, i am getting **ClassNotFoundException**. Could any one please let me know, how to include that plugins folder in classpath of WAS, so that i wont get ClassNotFoundException. I have added only runtime.jar in JVM classpath but it is throwing error as it is dependent on other jars of IBM.

Error : 
Caused by: **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection**

**Updated:**
**Currently it is working perfectly with Jboss server. Code below. My aim is to proivide the same provision with Webpshere.**

*Calling method:*

```
Connection connect = null;
connect = mDataSrc.getConnection();
unlockJDBC(connect);

private void unlockJDBC(Connection connect)
{
//This bit is JBoss specific but we are trying to avoid importing JBoss JAR files so we use reflection instead.

if (connect.getClass().getName().equals("org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedConnection") || connect.getClass().getSuperclass().getName().equals("org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedConnection"))
{
Method method = null;
try{
    method = connect.getClass().getMethod("getUnderlyingConnection",null);
    Connection conn = (Connection)method.invoke(connect, null);
    if (conn != null){
        connect = conn;
    }
}
catch (InvocationTargetException e){
    mLogger.severe(e.getTargetException().getMessage());
}
catch (Exception e){
    mLogger.severe(e.toString());
}
}
if (connect instanceof ExtEmbeddedConnection){
ExtEmbeddedConnection embConnect = (ExtEmbeddedConnection)connect;
try{
    embConnect.unlock("unlock");
}
catch (Exception e){
    mLogger.severe(e.toString());
}
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to get underlaying connection is to use proper JDBC API and unwrap it, like this (not using WebSphere internall classes):

```
Context ic = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource)ic.lookup("jdbc/OracleDS");
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();

// Returns true if this either implements the interface argument
// or is directly or indirectly a wrapper for an object that does.
if (conn.isWrapperFor(oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.class)) {
    // Returns an object that implements the given interface to
    // allow access to non-standard methods, or standard methods
    // not exposed by the proxy.
    oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection oraCon = conn.unwrap(oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.class);
    // Do some Oracle-specific work here.
}
```

For more details check the [WebSphere Application Server and the JDBC 4.0 Wrapper Pattern](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21577331)

**UPDATE**
In response to comments. I do not recommend this, although it works perfectly fine in WAS 8.5.5, so please fix your classpath and remove any WebSphere related jars you added there or packed with application:

```
        Connection connection = myDs.getConnection();
        System.out.println("connection: " + connection.getClass().getName());
        WSJdbcConnection conn = null;
        if(connection instanceof WSJdbcConnection) {
            System.out.println("WSJdbcConnection");
            conn = (WSJdbcConnection) connection;
            Object obj = WSJdbcUtil.getNativeConnection(conn);
            System.out.println("native: " + obj.getClass().getName());
        }
```

with output:

```
[8/11/15 16:55:10:165 CEST] 0000009a SystemOut     O connection: com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJccSQLJPDQConnection
[8/11/15 16:55:10:165 CEST] 0000009a SystemOut     O WSJdbcConnection
[8/11/15 16:55:10:165 CEST] 0000009a SystemOut     O native: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ef
```

Comment: Hi Gas, I am using branded JDBC connections. So, i cant use oracle jar directly. I had my product branded jar like myproductOracle.jar. the actually code i am trying is ((com.myproduct.jdbcx.oraclebase.BaseConnectionWrapper)(com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcUtil.getNativeConnection((com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection)connect))).unlock ("Password");. I have to cast my object from IBM connection object to my product object as mentioned above. Is there any way to include plugins folder in classpath of WAS.

Comment: @Naresh That jar is included in the classpath you dont have to do anything. `I have added only runtime.jar in JVM classpath` - if you added that jar manually anywhere please remove it from the classpath or application. This is causing you the problems. I can use that class without any changes.

Comment: @Naresh You could also try to use it with your wrapper like: `conn.isWrapperFor(com.myproduct.jdbcx.oraclebase.BaseConnectionWrapper.class)`. Oracle was put just for example here.

Comment: Thanks Gas and Bruce T for your great technical guidance. I was OOO since 2 days. I will try and get back to you ASAP.

Comment: Hi Gas, a bit delay from my end. I have tried with isWrapperFor but didnt work. Bcoz, "connect = mDataSrc.getConnection();" returns me WAS "com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection" object. So "connect.isWrapperFor(com.myproduct.jdbcx.oraclebase.BaseConnectionWrapper.class)" will always false. Plz let me know if i am wrong ..

Comment: Hi Gas, I just updated my question with the Jboss implementataion currently working in my application. I have to implement the same for WAS. Please support in achieving this as i was completely strucked here since long time.

Answer (score 0):

Websphere uses OSGI to limit visibility of internal classes to applications.  That could be what's happening here.  OSGI probably wasn't in play when you compiled it, but it is when you try to run it. If I do this in a servlet in v7,

```
ps.println("trying to new up a WSJdbcConnection");
Object o = com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection.class.newInstance();
ps.println("got it")
```

I get an IllegalAccessException, so it's not visible.

As Gas said, if you can use something that's not an internal, you should be able to access it.  Generally,
com.ibm.websphere - api,   com.ibm.wsspi - spi,  com.ibm.ws - internal