# can´t find rsadapterspi.jar to use WSJdbcConnection

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle11g, websphere

**WSJdbcConnection**, **WSJdbcUtil** these two showing errors in Web sphere 7 
but some systems working fine with same configuration some systems not working

```
        EWFUtil util=new EWFUtil();
        connection=util.getConnection();

        oracleConnection = (OracleConnection)WSJdbcUtil.getNativeConnection((WSJdbcConnection) connection);
```

Comment: What errors? Do you have errors during build or during runtime? Proper solution is to unwrap see http://stackoverflow.com/a/31745020/3701228

Answer (score 1):

WsJdbcUtil and WSJdbcConnection classes (as well as rsadapterspi.jar) are internals of the application server and should not be used by applications.

How does your application plan to use the OracleConnection?
You might be able to use public API WSCallHelper to invoke operations on OracleConnection or supply it to other Oracle utilities.  Refer to the knowledge center documentation:

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/apidocs/com/ibm/websphere/rsadapter/WSCallHelper.html

Alternately, if you are able to move up to a newer version of WebSphere Application Server, you can use the JDBC 4.0 spec defined wrapper pattern:

```
oracleConnection = connection.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
```